# In Angular, how do I abandon edits and restore the old object in list + list item components if both are data bound to object?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build on the Angular 'Heroes' tutorial (like so many!), where I am doing simple CRUD operations on a list of objects https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3 and the object edit component appears on the same page as the object list component, and the object service does REST calls to enable it all.

```html
<h2>Groups</h2>
<ul class="groups">
  <li *ngFor="let group of groups"
    [class.selected]="group === selectedGroup"
    (click)="onSelect(group)">
    {{group.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
<app-group-detail [group]="selectedGroup">

</app-group-detail>
```

app-group-detail:

```html
<div *ngIf="group">    
  <h2>{{group.name | uppercase}} Detail</h2>
  <div>
    <label>name:
      <input [(ngModel)]="group.name" placeholder="name"/>
    </label>
    <button (click)="save()">save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now my 'save item' works, and on success, there's nothing to do: both the object displayed in the list (by name) and the object in the edit item component and then the data in the DB are all in sync.

But then on error from the REST call, I'm trying to work out the most *Angular* approach. Currently, if the REST call errors, I have this situation:

- I show the error
- the data in the 'edit item' component's object is invalid and must be modified or discarded
- the data in the 'list' component is invalid because it is also data-bound to the object via its reference to it in the underlying array.

Now that would be fine if the user clicks a 'cancel' button, but they can also navigate away from the selected item in the list by selecting a different one.

What's the best approach?

Disallow clicking away and enforce use of a Cancel button?

Quietly abandon the edits by restoring the original values? (I store a copy in the edit component)

The example shows using `this.location.back()` but I can't see how that would work since my REST call doesn't cause a new page load that I could abandon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it depends on your parent-child implementation. In case your parent and child are totally different views you don't have to worry about the unsaved changes, you can just solve this problem by refreshing your parent view on `ngOnInit()` and fetch the data again which is a good practice for real scenarios as well ( there might be multiple users changing data constantly) so you always have the updated data. but if your parent is visible next to the child and parent can't be refreshed (losing the the selected row focus etc) you can get a hard copy of your data in child view and work with the copy and when API call successfully saves the data on server then you update the `Input()` object of child component with the returned object from API.
`app-group-detail.ts`

```html
  @Input() inputModel: DetailModel;
  localCopy: DetailModel;
ngOnChanges() {
    this.localCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.inputModel)); // or any other copy you like

    }
    save(){
    //call API to update using  this.localCopy 

    this.inputModel = // if call was successful get the reply object and put it in input
// Or better to use eventEmitters to send the object to the parent to be replaced 
// or just use eventemitters to notify the parent that it needs to be refreshed
    }
```

Hence you should use `localCopy` in your `app-group-detail.html` as binding.

In case you would like to use `eventEmitter` then you should define an event emitter in `app-group-detail.ts`. Following there are two approaches which you can use:

1. Emit event from the child just for the sake of notifying the parent that it needs to refresh the list. first, you need to define an Event Emitter in child using

```html
import {  EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Output() public updateEventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
// then emit this event when API call is successful to notify parent
save(){
   //API call to update resource and on successful case
   this.updateEventEmitter.emit();
 }
```

then the way to catch this event on paretn is when you want to define the child in parent's DOM file you need to do the following

```html
<app-group-detail (updateEventEmitter)="updateList()" [group]="selectedGroup">

</app-group-detail>
```

and in `parent.ts` define the `updateList()` function to update your list.

2. You can use the same pattern but sending the `object` of the updated resource from child to parent so parent replaces it (In case you need this) Just want to clarify how the pattern will look like. (exactly as above but with slight differences).

```html
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Output() dataUpdatedEventEmitter: EventEmitter<DataModel> = new EventEmitter();

save(){
// CALL API TO UPDATE
// On success emit the returned object
this.dataUpdatedEventEmitter.emit(objectToBeEmitted);
}
```

and in the parent's DOM file :

```html
<app-group-detail (dataUpdatedEventEmitter)="updateListWithItem($object)" [group]="selectedGroup">

</app-group-detail>
```

Comment: Parent and child are in the same page so I used event emitters to signal onCancel if the REST call failed, passing the original unedited object back out of the subcomponent via the event to replace the updated one sitting in the parent array. I also found https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/passing-data-to-and-raising-an-event-from-a-nested-component/ to be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to bind a copy of an object to `edit` component because there is multi cases that may cause an error (like internet connection).

So when edit the object you should call `edit api` and tell the parent ( list ) to refresh itself. after that the `list` component will recall its api and refresh its items.